# BOOTCAMP HDD move - Missing operating system

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup

A few weeks ago I put a bootcamp partition on my 320gb HDD in my mbp early 2009. However, a few days ago I bough me a 1tb hdd and exchanged it. Of course, I don't really want to re-install windows all over again, and just "copy" over my installed version.

After installing OS X I created a bootcamp partition and rebooted. I put my old HDD in a chassi and booted up into recovery-mode for OS X. Here I used the disk utility to "restore" the USB Bootcamp partition to the new Bootcamp partition. 
Now, when I boot, I can boot to the bootcamp partition, but as soon as it is boots I get the `Missing operating system` error.

I tried booting from the original windows 7 disk and choose repair, but get the message that I cannot repair the current version of windows since its not the same version.

How can I solve this, without reinstalling windows?

Comment: With both the old drive and the new one attached, can you please open a Terminal window and add the output from running these commands to your question: `diskutil list` - check what your new and old disk are called, let's assume disk0 and disk1, then run: `sudo gpt -r show disk0`, `sudo gpt -r show disk1`, `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`, `sudo fdisk /dev/disk1`. This tells us the OSX and Windows partition tables on both disks, and might give us a clue as to where to start fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. unfortunately... I didn't got it working. So, I ended up making a new partition for windows and re-installing it. Too bad I wasted so much time.